# Month closest actual month

Tags: sql, getdate

i have this table:

```
Players:
ID (int)
Birthday (datetime)
```

I need choose 3 first players, which have birthday in the actual month...
I have this but the result is nothing.. Have you any idea?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Players
WHERE Birthday < DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SQL Server syntax:

```
select  top 3 *
from    YourTable
where   datepart(month, Birthday) = datepart(month, getdate())
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use DATEPART function in SQL server

```
SELECT * 
FROM Players
WHERE DATEPART(MM,Birthday) = DATEPART(MM,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Kate says: I need choose 3 first players. does your query will return 3 first player?